# Prevent Python fron binding class variables of different type

Tags: python

I ran across interesting function binding behavior:

```
class MyClass:
    def run(self):
        print(type(self))

class MyHelperClass:
    bar = MyClass.run

    def foo(self):
        self.bar()
        MyHelperClass.bar()
```

When I run `MyHelperClass().foo()`, this happens:

```
<class '__main__.MyHelperClass'>
# but run() isn't in this class

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    MyHelperClass.bar()
TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
# this makes sense
```

The class variable gets bound to `self` when I access it from `self`, even though the type is incompatible? And when I access it on the class, there's nothing to bind to, so it's left unbound?

I was able to prevent the method from being bound by doing `bar = functools.partial(MyClass.run)`.

Is my understanding of why it was bound correct? Is there even a difference between having class var that's an unbound function and a standard instance method?

Is there a better way to keep the method from being bound than `partial()`?

Comment: "The class variable gets bound to self when I access it from self, even though the type is incompatible? " What? The type isn't incompatible. "And when I access it on the class, there's nothing to bind to, so it's left unbound?" Of course, this is **always** the behavior. Try `MyClass.run()`, you'll get a similar error for the same reason

Comment: It isn't being bound because it isn't a function anymore when you do `bar = functools.partial(MyClass.run)` The binding happens because *function objects are descriptors*.  It isn't really clear what you are trying to accomplish, though. An alternative is to do something like `self.bar = MyClass.run`, then if you do `self.bar()` it won't automatically bind the instance as the first argument